# Scikit learn Iterative Imputer : change and scaled tolerance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, missing-data

As part of a school project, I have to explore and perform data analysis and machine learning methods on a given database. The point is that my database is pretty big (12 651 lines for 810 columns) and contains a lot of missing values.
I wanted to impute these values with the Iterative Imputer of Scikit-learn, and this is what I get:

```
imp = IterativeImputer(estimator = LinearRegression(), 
                       max_iter=10, 
                       random_state=0, 
                       verbose=2, 
                       n_nearest_features=10, 
                       initial_strategy="most_frequent")

imp.fit(data)
```

Results:

```
IterativeImputer] Completing matrix with shape (12651, 810)
[IterativeImputer] Ending imputation round 1/10, elapsed time 8.38
[IterativeImputer] Change: 101844979.96577276, scaled tolerance: 208867.02000000002 
[IterativeImputer] Ending imputation round 2/10, elapsed time 18.76
[IterativeImputer] Change: 633298988.0233588, scaled tolerance: 208867.02000000002 
[IterativeImputer] Ending imputation round 3/10, elapsed time 28.81
[IterativeImputer] Change: 591554347.9059296, scaled tolerance: 208867.02000000002 
[IterativeImputer] Ending imputation round 4/10, elapsed time 37.43
[IterativeImputer] Change: 1289773197.9995384, scaled tolerance: 208867.02000000002 
[IterativeImputer] Ending imputation round 5/10, elapsed time 46.58
[IterativeImputer] Change: 1291562921.1247401, scaled tolerance: 208867.02000000002 
[IterativeImputer] Ending imputation round 6/10, elapsed time 54.32
[IterativeImputer] Change: 32943821.50762498, scaled tolerance: 208867.02000000002 
[IterativeImputer] Ending imputation round 7/10, elapsed time 64.13
[IterativeImputer] Change: 58342050.73579848, scaled tolerance: 208867.02000000002 
[IterativeImputer] Ending imputation round 8/10, elapsed time 73.44
[IterativeImputer] Change: 1559818227.7418892, scaled tolerance: 208867.02000000002 
[IterativeImputer] Ending imputation round 9/10, elapsed time 81.46
[IterativeImputer] Change: 164792431487.71582, scaled tolerance: 208867.02000000002 
[IterativeImputer] Ending imputation round 10/10, elapsed time 90.07
[IterativeImputer] Change: 13045775634991.55, scaled tolerance: 208867.02000000002
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/sklearn/impute/_iterative.py:785: ConvergenceWarning: [IterativeImputer] Early stopping criterion not reached.
  warnings.warn(
```

I don't know if i can do anything to make it converge?
Thanks!

P.s: One thing I did not mention is that many of the columns actually represent categorical variables (but pandas casted these columns as float64 because of the NaN values).

What I tried: changing the estimator from BayesianRidge to LinearRegressor, setting n_nearest_features = 10 and 20, setting initial_strategy="most_frequent" instead of "mean". It did not seem to work either :/

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data you are trying to fit?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different things you can try to get better results with IterativeImputer. The first thing I would do is try some regularization by using either Ridge or ElasticNet as your estimator, and increasing max_iter to ~50 to see if your results ever stabilize.

In my personal experience I also have better success if I scale the data before imputing and choose `initial_strategy="median"` rather than `'most_frequent'`.

If you have a mix of continuous and categorical features, you will likely need a nonlinear estimator and will need to postprocess the results by re-quantizing the categorical features.

Comment: I tried to replace "most_frequent" by "median" and increase max_iter to 50, it did not change anything. Actually, another problem that I am facing is to even differentiate qualitative features from quantitative ones... I'll think about it and come back if I have anything new!

Comment: I've managed to transform categorical variables into dummy variables. But I am now facing the same problem: scaled tolerance = 208867.02000000002 does not seem to vary. Also, what does 'Scaled tolerance' and 'change' stand for?

Comment: `scaled tolerance` is the stopping condition; it won't change between iterations. It is (naively) based on the value of your largest feature. 

`change` is the norm distance between the feature matrices between subsequent iterations; if it is ever below `scaled_tolerance`, your imputation is assumed to have converged. The convergence criteria doesn't really make a lot of sense, but if `change` isn't decreasing (or at least roughly constant), you definitely haven't reached convergence.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Actually, I found a way out: I wanted to drop irrelevant columns of my database anyway, and was assuming that I would do so by first impute missing values, then applying Lasso regularization to drop variables whose coefficients were null. But it turns out it is possible to apply Lasso even with missing values (see HMLasso, "Lasso with High missing rate" in Google)